# Using regex replace() method to remove delimiters and capitalise first letters in one step

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, regex-lookarounds

I've developed the following function (also available in this codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/RRKjex) when trying to remove all underscore delimiters and convert the first letters to upper case.

**Objective:**

Given `'this_is_some_text'` as an input string, the function should return `'ThisIsSomeText'`.

**Working JS code:**

```
function capitaliseFirst(str) {
  var firstCapital = str.replace(/[a-z]+/g, x => x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1));
  return firstCapital.replace(/_/g, '')
}

console.log( capitaliseFirst('this_is_some_text') ); // returns ThisIsSomeText
```

The function above achieves the desired objective, however I would like to refactor it so that only one `replace()` method is required. At the moment I'm stuck at the code below. Would you know how this could be completed?

**Not working (yet) JS code:**

```
function capitaliseFirst2(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:_)?([a-z])/g, '$1')
}

console.log( capitaliseFirst2('some_other_text') ); // should return SomeOtherText
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
function capitaliseFirst2(str) {
    return str.replace(/(?:_+|^)(.)/g, (m0, m1) => m1.toUpperCase());
}
```

We match and capitalize every character that comes after 1 or more underscores or the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regexp, I suggest you to do it just writing code:

```
function capitaliseFirst2(str) {
  return str.split('_').map(function(w) {
    return w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return (a + b)
  });
}
```

I'm not sure about performace issues comparing to the regexp, but it is much more readable, than a regexp.

Comment: That `.reduce` looks a lot like `.join('')` to me.

Comment: I did a couple of speed tests and the `.replace` with regex is better, but not so dramatic. Of course you could use `.join('')` too instead of `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another short solution using ES6 arrow function as to `Array.forEach` function:

```
var str = 'this_is_some_text', capitalized = "";
    str.split("_").forEach((s) => (capitalized += s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)));

console.log(capitalized);  // "ThisIsSomeText"
```